# HTML/CSS div not recognised In Ruby on Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Im currently following a Ruby on Rails tutorial but I seem to be making a mistake which I can't seem to grasp. If you'd ask me I'd say it's a syntax error but I just don't know where.

In my HTML.ERB file, I create a div called columns. In this columns div I also have a main div. In my CSS file I try to assign some CSS commands to my div. Strangely enough the #main div however does not get highlighted, and when running the app the main div also does not get the things i just assigned to it, like a white background color. Could anyone help me with this? I have a feeling I'm making a silly mistake

HTML.ERB file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>
    <div id="banner">
        <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
        <%= @page_title || "Pragmatic Bookshelf" %>
    </div>
    <div id="columns">
        <div id="side">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www....">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www..../faq">Questions</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www..../news">News</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www..../contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <div id="main"> 
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS File:

```
#columns {
  background: #141;

   #main {
     margin-left: 17em;
     padding: 1em;
     background: white;
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using SCSS syntax?

Comment: yes my bad i did. It seemed it was a problem with file extensions as i saved in .css instead of .css.scss. Thanks for pointing me towards it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was changing my file extension. I saved to .css.scss instead of .css and it works now.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are not editing css then, you are editing a sass file. Sass is a CSS preprocessor which makes easier for you to write your css but it has to be precompiled into css for the browser to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to use less syntax for your CSS rules. CSS does not allow nested selectors. Thy this:

```
#columns {
  background: #141;
}

#columns #main {
  margin-left: 17em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
}
```